# jquery dialog text disappear only for 2nd time opening

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following jquery code to pop up a dialog. It works fine for the first time. However, when the dialog closed, and I opened it again, the dialog text area is empty (no text displayed) with only three buttons. Now, if I reopen it again (3rd time, 4th time ...), everything works fine again (text was shown). As you can tell from the name, the function buttonClicked() to pop up the dialog is triggered by clicking a button. So anyone has any clue?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        function buttonClicked() {
           var dialog = $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                buttons: {
                    "Cancel":  function() {
                        $(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
                    },
                    "Button2": function() {
                        // do something
                        $(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
                    },
                    "Button1":  function() {
                        ... // do something
                        $(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });

            dialog .dialog( "open" ); 
        }


          <div id = "dialog" name="dialog" style="display:none; ">
          <style>
            .ui-dialog-titlebar-close .ui-icon-closethick {
              position: relative !important;
              margin-top: -9px  !important;
              margin-left: -16px  !important;
            }
          </style>
          <p>I am the text shown in the dialog!!</p></div>
```

Comment: How are you opening the dialog? The only code you have above that does that is when the page loads with `dialog.dialog("open");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$( function() {
       $("#dialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                "Cancel":  function() {
                    $(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
                },
                "Button2": function() {
                    // do something
                    $(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
                },
                "Button1":  function() {
                    ... // do something
                    $(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
      $('#yourBtn').click(function(){
          $("#dialog").dialog('open');
      }) 

    }
```